# Problema con Sentencias preparadas MYSQL php

Tags: php, mysql

No consigo arreglar esta consulta desde `php`, el error es el siguiente:

> "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in...."

y la consulta es la siguiente:

```
private function consultMySql(){

        $cSQL = "SELECT SUM(CRIME.id), " .
                "PRIMARY_TYPE.Type " .
                "FROM CRIMES.CRIME " .
                "INNER JOIN PRIMARY_TYPE " .
                "ON CRIME.Type = PRIMARY_TYPE.id " .
                "WHERE Distric = ? AND " .
                "PRIMARY_TYPE.Type = ? " .
                "AND CRIME.anno = ?; "  ;

        if($this->stmt = $this->oConni->prepare($cSQL)){
        $this->stmt->bind_param('isi', $this->request["data"]["district"], $this->request["data"]["type"],$this->request["data"]["anno"] );
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $this->stmt->store_result();
        $this->stmt->bind_result($Total, $Type);
        while ($this->stmt->fetch()) {
            $this->data[] = array("Total" => $Total, "Type" => $Type);
        }
        }else{
            $this->stmt->error;
        }

    }
```

El caso es que la consulta la he probado con el `Navicat` y funciona correctamente, la cadena la he visto por consola y también parece bien formada, no tiene ninguna espacio mal hecho, la conexión a la base de datos también es correcta.

Comment: ¿La tabla es CRIMES o CRIME?  Parece que en unas partes lo pones con S y en otras sin S.

Comment: Al parecer CRIMES es el schema y CRIME es la tabla

Comment: @jolsalazar buena vista. Se me había pasado esa posibilidad. ¿Que se indique la interfaz en algunos sitios pero no en otros  puede traer problemas de algún tipo?

Comment: Si se especifica el schema donde se trabaja no deberia dar error, ahora obviamente que si se indico en la primera vez deberia haberse hecho lo mismo con la tabla `PRIMARY_TYPE`, pero bueno... será que `$this` en realidad no tiene la conexion por ende tampoco puede ejecutar `bind_param`